# Is it a bad practice to use multiple nested If Else statements?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a validator for an interface to change the password, and while making it I realized that I was using a lot of `if else` statements. I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

My Code :

```js
function changePassword() {

  var testPassword = "user";
  var oldPassword = document.getElementById('password-old').value;
  var newPassword = document.getElementById('password-new').value;
  var newPasswordRepeat = document.getElementById('password-new-repeat').value;

  if (oldPassword === testPassword) {
    if (newPassword !== newPasswordRepeat) {
      alert("The passwords don't match");
    } else {
      if (newPassword === "") {
        alert("New password can't be blank");
      } else {
        alert("Password was changed successfully");
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect Password")
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="password-old">Old Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-old" />

<label for="password-new">New Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-new" />

<label for="password-new-repeat">Re-Enter New Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-new-repeat" />

<input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="changePassword()" />
```

Is there a shorter way to do it or should I keep it as it is?

Comment: This question belongs at codereview, rather than here

Comment: @mplungjan sorry about that, im still pretty new here so i wasnt fully aware about that site. ill use that next time :)

Comment: See this post on the sister site Software Engineering: [How would you refactor nested IF Statements?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements). Note this post too is a duplicate which links to further posts on this subject. As this is a very broad and opinion-based topic, it's not a good fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: The snippet doesn't appear to work. It shows me Incorrect Password even when I'm absolutely sure I've made a new password that's according to all rules. A proper validator would tell exactly which rule is violated, which yours doesn't.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica thanks! ill check that now

Comment: @Mast yes, I didnt add the code that changes the password yet. this is only to validate it

Comment: @pokerface0958 The validator returns wrongly, that's the problem.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica I don't think that's a particularly useful close reason. Closing it as Too Broad (Need additional details) would suffice.

Comment: @Mast as in? i checked again and it worked for me. could you explain if you dont mind? maybe i missed something

Comment: @Mast As those sites deal specifically with this kind of topic, it seems to me as the best fit.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica As a regular on Code Review, I can say for certain questions are never a good fit at both sites (CR & Software) at the same time.

Comment: is there any way i can close this without deleting it if thats an issue? i got a better idea on what i need from the answers

Comment: @pokerface0958 A question cannot be deleted once it has an answer with upvotes or an accepted answer. See [How does deleting works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). You can post another question.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica oh my bad, I didnt know that. thank you for that link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return early.

```js
function changePassword() {

  var testPassword = "user";
  var oldPassword = document.getElementById('password-old').value;
  var newPassword = document.getElementById('password-new').value;
  var newPasswordRepeat = document.getElementById('password-new-repeat').value;

  if (oldPassword !== testPassword) return alert("Incorrect Password");
  if (newPassword !== newPasswordRepeat) return alert("The passwords don't match");
  if (newPassword === "") return alert("New password can't be blank");
  alert("Password was changed successfully");
}
```

```html
<label for="password-old">Old Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-old" />

<label for="password-new">New Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-new" />

<label for="password-new-repeat">Re-Enter New Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password-new-repeat" />

<input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="changePassword()" />
```

Comment: Alert does not have a return value

Comment: @mplungjan I think that all functions in JavaScript have a return value. If I use `let x = alert("The passwords don't match");`, `x` will be `undefined`.

Comment: it is just the idea of return early. it is up to op to fill the return value with something useful.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank you for this. your code looks much cleaner than mine. this is the only function im going to need from the script so usng `alert` as a return wouldnt cause any problems right?

Comment: right. if you are unsure, you could separate the function call and return statement.

Comment: I do not recommend to shortcut using the undefined return value of alert. In my example, the default action of the button is stopped by returning false on errors

Answer (score 3):

I would shortcut for readability

Note I specifically return a true or false and not a `falsy` or no value as in the other answers.

In OP's example the script is executed on click of a button.
Using my code you can attach it to an event handler or use it in another statement that needs the result of the changePassword function. For example:

```js
function changePassword() {

  var testPassword = "user";
  var oldPassword = document.getElementById('password-old').value;
  var newPassword = document.getElementById('password-new').value;
  var newPasswordRepeat = document.getElementById('password-new-repeat').value;

  if (newPassword === "") {
    alert("New password can't be blank");
    return false;
  }
  if (oldPassword !== testPassword) {
    alert("Incorrect Password")
    return false;
  }
  const valid = newPassword === newPasswordRepeat
  alert(valid ? "Password was changed successfully" : "The passwords don't match");
  return valid;
}

const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
const success = document.getElementById("success");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // we do not submit (you could if you wanted though) 
  const passWordChanged = changePassword();
  myForm.hidden = passWordChanged; // the form will hide when successful
  success.hidden = !passWordChanged; // show (hidden = false)
  
});
```

```css
.form-container {
  width: 50%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the form in the page */
}

.form-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(200px, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  text-align: right; /* Align text to the right for labels */
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%; /* Input takes the full width of its grid area */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: 2; /* Position the submit button under the inputs */
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="success" hidden>Password successfully changed</h1>
<div class="form-container">
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="password-old">Old Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="password-old" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="password-new">New Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="password-new" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="password-new-repeat">Re-Enter New Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="password-new-repeat" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this. this definitely looks cleaner than using multiple `if else` statements

Comment: @pokerface0958 Please note the return  in `return changePassword()` because I explicit set the true or false, the button action is stopped when an error occurred

Answer (score 1):

Yes. those nested if statements tend to decrease the readability. In your case, you can simply return from the method to avoid the nesting and make the code more understandable.

```
function changePassword() {

  var testPassword = "user";
  var oldPassword = document.getElementById('password-old').value;
  var newPassword = document.getElementById('password-new').value;
  var newPasswordRepeat = document.getElementById('password-new-repeat').value;

  if (oldPassword !== testPassword) {
    alert("Incorrect Password")
    return
  }

  if (newPassword !== newPasswordRepeat) {
    alert("The passwords don't match");
    return;
  }

  if (newPassword === "") {
    alert("New password can't be blank");
  } else {
    alert("Password was changed successfully");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually multiple nested if else increases [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and thus should be avoided wherever is possible.

> Cyclomatic complexity is defined as the number of linearly independent paths through the code.

So you should refactor your code to have less branches. You can rewrite your function as:

```html
function changePassword() {

      var testPassword = "user";
      var oldPassword = document.getElementById('password-old').value;
      var newPassword = document.getElementById('password-new').value;
      var newPasswordRepeat = document.getElementById('password-new-repeat').value;

      if (oldPassword != testPassword) {  
        alert("Incorrect Password")
      }
      else if (newPassword !== newPasswordRepeat) {
        alert("The passwords don't match");
      }  
      else if (newPassword === "") {
        alert("New password can't be blank");
      }
      else {
        alert("Password was changed successfully");
      }
}
```